# How to sing rock like this?

Tags: voice, distortion, rock-n-roll

Can anyone please explain in technical terms how Richie Kotzen achives the singing voice in this song? The more singing terminology the better.
Thank you !
[Richie Kotzen - Mother Head's Family Reunion](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DtP8VCC-a_s)

Comment: As for the tone, related: https://music.stackexchange.com/q/79614/45266, although disclaimer: I wrote the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Cool video! He seems to be using a strong head voice (aka reinforced falsetto), which he is blending very nicely with his chest voice to create a smooth mixed voice with a nice, rocky tone.

I suggest you look into 'head voice', if you don't know what that is (the upper register above the chest voice). Apparently it can be strengthened and then blended with the chest voice to create a 'mixed' voice, although doing that may take quite a lot of time/training, depending on your level of ability.

As anyone will tell you, the best (and safest) option is to find a good vocal coach (although I've been seeing some improvement myself following some of [this guy's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hEZXkRYf-w0) videos on YouTube).